# top left pixel coordinates ios (0,0) or (1,1)?

Tags: ios

Considering the screen resolutions of ios device is (320*480) points. What is the point value of top left pixel? Is it 0,0 or 1,1 ?

Comment: It starts at (0,0), yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(0, 0)`. In computing world, numbering *always* starts at zero. That's how you can tell between programmers and other people: tell them to count to ten.

Comment: Not all languages count from 0. For example, Lua always starts indices at 1.

Comment: Didn't know, but that's interesting. I use(d) [Object] Pascal, Basic, [Objective-]C[++], JavaScript, Java, Caml, Prolog, and perhaps others, and they all start at zero. Heck, even POV starts at zero ;)

Answer (score 5):

Technically, the top-left pixel is actually a rect that stretches from `{0, 0}` to `{1, 1}`, with the center point at `{0.5, 0.5}`.

When expressing rects, to include the top-left pixel you want to start at `{0, 0}`. But, for example, if you want to draw a line that's centered on the top-left pixel, then your line needs to pass through `{0.5, 0.5}`.

Comment: Let a user taps the top left pixel and we get the location of the top left pixel in a (CGPoint  point)struct. What is point.x and point.y in this case ?

Comment: Coordinates used by UIKit (tap locations, view frames, etc) tend to be integral, so it would probably be `{0,0}`.